# Functions defined on General sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

I am learning how to determined whether a function is well defined. I am doing so by relying on two disticnt reasons that show a not well defined function: (1) There is no y that satisfies  the given equation or (2) there are two different values of y that satisfy the quation.

I am having difficulties determining if the following function is well defined:

On certain computers the integer data type goes from $-2, 147, 483, 648$ through $2, 147, 483, 647$. Let S be the set of all integers from $-2, 147, 483, 648$ through $2, 147, 483, 647$. Try to define a function $f:S  -> S$ by the rule $f(n) = n^2$ for each n in S. Is f well defined? Why?